# Auto rotation to a segment controller in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, autorotate

I am working on an application in which a segment controller is added as a sub view as follows:

```
{
    segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",nil]];
    [segment setFrame:CGRectMake(70, 22, 200, 40)];
    [segment setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStylePlain];
    [window addSubview:segment];
}
```

which is in the app delegate. Auto rotation is enabled in my application in other views. But how can I give autorotation to this segment controller which is added in the app delegate. Anyone have the answer? Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be better if you also set your segment controller co ordinate in below method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

return YES;}
```

in every class.Just try I hope it will be work. let me know if any clarification.

Comment: sandy,should i use this method in app delegate

Comment: How can i get the control of segment controller in other views,which is added in the app delegate.

Comment: use appdelegate object and access the segment controller

Comment: if still you have any problem then let me show ur code I'll tell u